# Live-USB vs Bootable-USB vs USBwithOSonly

Tags: bootable-media, partition-recovery, boot-partition, usb-boot, bootrepair

So much confusion amongst those three.

Say I have a Laptop with C: drive only which is  crashed and not booting up..probably a corrupt MBR or MFT...and I want to recover the C:

Having not enough space in C: ,  I need to examine and do recovery. I definitely need  another drive from which I can run same OS.

I read a few and found an OS on USB can provision the environment as: 
   Live-USB / Bootable-USB

I will be using Rufus/WinToUSB to install an *Win 7 Pro SP1* ISO.

But

1. Which ISO should I select - Bootable or Non bootable ?
2. What type of USB environment should be created ***such that I can examine C:*** -

   - a. Live-USB
   - b. Bootable-USB
   - c. non-bootable-non-live
     USB(with just ISO image of same OS)

Help much appreciated ahead...with a little description of the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A live USB, e.g. [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), is a bootable device. Once you enable booting from USB in BIOS/UEFI (usually, just change boot order, possibly disable Fast Boot -- disabling Secure Boot should no longer be needed), you can boot from flash USB into the new OS, *without having to install the OS on your HDD*. You may need to [mount the existing HDD](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mount-drive-from-command-line-ubuntu-linux/), or it may already be mounted on booting. **This should give you access to the HDD, and allow you to copy files to another drive before making any changes.** At one time, Microsoft offered [Windows To Go](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview), a live, bootable Windows 10, but, "Windows To Go is no longer being developed." There is [Windows PE](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-windows-pe), which is very limited, but might work for your purpose. Easiest way to build it and to make a live, bootable WinPE USB drive is with [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree). This would also enable you to **image the disk before making changes**.
- A bootable, but not live, drive would allow you to boot to *install* the OS on your PC, but likely would destroy existing files in the process.
- Another option is a [live, bootable USB drive *with persistent storage*](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/). This is essentially a portable operating system, with the added ability to store changes you've made on the flash drive. Since flash memory is slow, this is probably not what you need, but it gives the ability to walk up to a new computer, plug in the drive, and boot into a session you began earlier on another PC.
- A non-bootable drive would be of no use to you, if your HDD cannot boot.

After you've salvaged files, you have a few options:

- Try to restore your HDD to its original OS, without installing the new OS on the USB.
- If you can restore the OS, you might install the new OS in a dual-boot configuration, giving you access to either at startup.
- If it's not feasible to restore the old OS, you might install the alternative OS.

As far as what ISO to use, use one compatible with your PC. E.G., 32-bit or 64-bit, desktop or server. There are [many Linux distributions](https://www.lifewire.com/top-ubuntu-alternatives-4135701) and other free operating systems, a matter of personal choice. Though I am comfortable creating and using Ubuntu, others may prefer Mint, derived from Ubuntu, or Fedora. If the PC is low-end, Puppy Linux, Simplicity Linux and Lubuntu require fewer resources.

Comment: Thats close thanks..As I am totally on windows, and say i create a compatible LiveUSB of Win7Pro along with correct BIOS settings. Then after restart, how to mount the C Drive ? Is there an option to auto mount the C while creating a LiveUSB of Windows? Read few - many said HDD wont be visible...I sud definitely give it a try. Yet just clearing my strategies before I jump into somthing straight ahead just to find later I misunderstood and took a wrong path

Comment: With Rufus 3.9.1 I created Bootable USB..but there was no option for "LiveUSB" or "Run Windows on this drive". I see while rebooting with F12 and choosing Boot from "USB storage device" it boots really from USB but not as a Windows desktop but asking to Install Windows. Is this bcoz its Win7 or bcoz not Rufis 3.5.x or 3.8.x ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Microsoft no longer designs Windows 10 as a live, bootable, OS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview ("Windows To Go is no longer being developed.") There is Windows PE, https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-windows-pe , which is very limited, but might work for your purpose. Easiest way to build it is with Macrium reflect, which would also enable you to image the disk before making changes.

Comment: Thanks..let me try a few...btw its not Win10 but Win7..WinToUSB worked...I am able to run Win7 from my USB (instead of HDD).

Comment: All worked...now its upto the recovery softwares to detect..Thanks a ton :)   Acceptng as your help was absolute and tapped right on the nerve

Comment: Glad it helped you and your PC is working again!